# Send Json from PhoneGap to remote php Server

Tags: php, ajax

i try to send a json Array via Ajax to a remote PHP Server, but i only get a "ParserError".
Thank you

Ajax

```
$.ajax({
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    jsonp : 'jsonp_callback',
    data : {
        button : "test"
    },
    url : 'http://www.my-server.de/file.php',
    success : function(sqlArray) {
        alert(sqlArray);
    },

    error : function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown) {
        alert(jqXHR);
        alert(textStatus);
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

PHP

```
 <?php
 echo "Button ist";
 echo  $_GET['button'];
 ?>
```

## **UPdate:**

Thank you, but i only want to write out the value of the json object.
Now the sending work, but the php site don´t write the value.

```
function postJSON(){
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://www.my-server.de/file.php",
    data: { 'dataString': "juhu" },
    cache: false,
    success: function()
        {
            alert("Order Submitted");
        },
        error: function()
        {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
```

php:

```
<?php 
 echo "Value is:";
 echo $_GET['dataString']; ?>
```

Comment: You are waiting for json data, your php script does not return anything. Try echoing at least this : `echo json_encode(array());` to see if it still throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

Just json_encode() wont do the job. Since you are using jsonp as a datatype you need to return a callback function - this is what I use:

```
public static function renderJsonp($object) {
        header('Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf8');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 3628800');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');

        header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

        $callback = "callback";
        if(isset($_GET['callback'])) $callback = trim($_GET['callback']);

        echo $callback . '(' . json_encode($object) . ')';
    }
```

Use stdClass() to create the Object.